# writing a file to open a selection of files

Tags: python, function

im trying to write a file that will open 1 of 2 text files.
i want it to pop up with a little question asking do you want file 1 or 2, then when i choose that file it just opens that one. i don't think its happy with my choice of how to decide though.

1=p.txt and 2 = q.txt btw

```
def open_function (f):
    print('which file would you like? type 1 for p and 2 for q')
    choice = raw_input('> ')
    if choice == 1:
    file_choice=p.txt
    elif choice == 2:  
        file_choice=q.txt

f=open('file_choice','r')
for i in range (1):                     first_line=f.readline()
rest=f.readlines()

f.close
```

i keep getting

```
File "<ipython-input-10-383b19133bad>", line 6
elif choice == 2:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what can i do to make a choice here between the 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indentation is broken.  Indent the line after the `if` like:

```
if choice == 1:
    file_choice = 'p.txt'
elif choice == 2:  
    file_choice = 'q.txt'
```

In addition, you will need to quote your strings as shown.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify an `int` for comparison in the `raw_input`
2. Indentation is incorrect.
3. You need to put the file names into quotes.
4. You do not need a print function.. You can add it into the `raw_input`
5. You need to take 'file_choice` out of quotes for opening the file.

   ```
   def open_function (f):

       #print('which file would you like? type 1 for p and 2 for q')
       choice = int(raw_input('which file would you like? type 1 for p and 2 for q > '))
       if choice == 1:
           file_choice='p.txt'
       elif choice == 2:  
           file_choice='q.txt'

       f=open(file_choice,'r')
       for i in range (1):                     
           first_line=f.readline()
           rest=f.readlines()

       f.close
   ```